# Selectable Website Background

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, background-image

How can I add something to my website that allows users to choose from three backgrounds?

I don't know if this will require Javascript, or CSS, or HTML (I am relatively new to web design)

(This is a very simple question, but I have not found it via Google)

Answer (score 2):

Try this method. its very simple for what you want.
Here i provide a drop down menu but you can use any input selector.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function switchBG(){
var img = document.getElementById("theSwitch").value;
var page = document.getElementById("pageBody");

if(img == 1){
    page.className = "bgOne";
} else if(img == 2){
    page.className = "bgTwo";
} else if(img == 3){
    page.className = "bgThree";
}
}
</script>

<style type="text/css">
.bgOne{
    background:url(1.png)
}
.bgTwo{
    background:url(2.png)
}
.bgThree{
    background:url(3.png)
}
</style>

<div id="pageBody" class="bgOne">
<select id="theSwitch" onchange="switchBG()">
  <option value="0">Choose Background</option>
  <option value="1">BG 1</option>
  <option value="2">BG 2</option>
  <option value="3">BG 3</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: When I use this code, it does not change the background. It only changes the background of the actual options thing.

Comment: I want it to change the actual background of the body.

Comment: add the class inside your body tag. sorry i thought it. was obvious. change the div to body 

`<body id="pageBody" class="bgOne">` sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1):

I think this question is way too broad but I'll give it a try anyway :)

You can use this JavaScript to set the background image of your website to one of 3 (ore more) where *selectedImage* is the array index of the selected image:

```
var bgImages = ['image1.png', 'image2.jpg', 'http://example.com/image3.gif'];
var selectedImage = 0;

document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + bgImages[selectedImage % bgImages.length] + "')";
```

If you want to save your users selection you could use [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/cookie) or the new HTML5 [Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API).

I suppose you want to update the background image on page load. To do this you could put the your javascript into the . You could also put it in the  but than you have to wait for the '[DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded)' event because document.body won't be available before that.

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
        //code goes here
    });
</script>
```

The jquery solution for that would be

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    //you code goes here
  });
</script>
```

In my opinion the best thing would be to do all this on the server side (e.g. with php) but regarding your tags it looks like you are not looking for a solution like that.

I suggest you have a look at some of the links in this answer and try to solve it yourself. Please do not expect stackoverflow users to code everything for you. Try to break down your problem and ask more specific questions like 'How do I change the background image with javascript' and I'm sure you'll find heaps of answers here...